# Error when loading WebAssembly file from NestJs backend

Tags: nestjs, webassembly

I'm trying to load a WebAssembly file into the browser. I'm trying to load [this](https://github.com/niklasf/stockfish.js#readme) library and when I try to do what is described I get an error

```
const worker = new Worker('http://localhost:3000/webworker-wasm')
VM114:1 Refused to create a worker from 'http://localhost:3000/webworker-wasm' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'worker-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

So I guess it has to do with how I serve that file. I have a [NestJS](https://github.com/nestjs/nest) backend, and the code serving that file looks like

```
@Get('webworker-wasm')
private getWebworkerWasm(req: Request, res: Response) {
    fs.readFile('./node_modules/stockfish.js/stockfish.wasm.js', (err: any, data: Buffer) => {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/wasm'});
        res.status(200).end(data);
    });
}
```

Is there anything in this setup that is incorrect or did I forget something?

UPDATE:  I've changed the code a bit and now the error is a bit different

```
   fs.readFile('./node_modules/stockfish.js/stockfish.wasm.js', 'binary', (err: any, data: Buffer) => {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/wasm');

        // res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/wasm'});
        res.status(200).end(data);
    });
```

gives:

```
x = new Worker('http://localhost:3000/files/webworker-wasm');
VM48:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'http://localhost:3000/files/webworker-wasm' cannot be accessed from origin 'chrome-search://local-ntp'.
at <anonymous>:1:5
```

My my case its fine if I can fix this with a chrome setting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can’t add a comment, so I post this as an answer.

Please post all the response headers as seen in the browser.

Also, you’re serving a JavaScript file as WebAssembly, `application/wasm` should be `application/javascript`.

Comment: You're right. It is javascript. It turns out that that javascript loads the wasm file